# Turn typescript interface property types into union

Tags: typescript

I have this interface, and I would like to generate a new type from the type of keys it contains.

```
interface SomeType {
  abc: string;
  def: number;
  ghi: boolean;
}
```

Type to generate:

```
type SomeOtherType = string | number | boolean
```

Is this possible in typescript?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of `keyof`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to index with a keyof operator:

```
interface SomeType {
  abc: string;
  def: number;
  ghi: "sdf";
}

type t = SomeType[keyof SomeType];
```

The type t will be assumed as a type union that comes from the values of the object:
[image]

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG8AoZZOAIwQC5kBnMKUAcwG5zkATCGekAFdMVaJwqsAFsHoAiBtxizOAX1KkwhFGGQBeNFlxaA2gGsIedDAPZ8RALrsgA

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: @jcalz fixed :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a trick to generate the values of an interface:

```
interface SomeType {
  abc: string;
  def: number;
  ghi: boolean;
}

//First generate a type that works as a "valueof" (similar to keyof)
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

//Then obtain the values
type Values = ValueOf<SomeType> // Values = string | number | boolean
//ValueOf re-usable component, however it is enough also SomeType[keyof SomeType]

//If you need the keys on the other hand "keyof" is enough:
type Keys = keyof SomeType // Keys = 'abc' | 'def' | 'ghi'
```