# How to prevent Union type from expecting irrelevant keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function `getRespectiveConfig()` returning a Union type consisting of all the types I need to be return:

```js
interface AlphaConfig {
    title: string;
}

interface BetaConfig {
    id: string;
}

export interface EncompassingConfig {
    alphaConfig?: AlphaConfig;
    betaConfig?: BetaConfig;
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type RespectiveConfig = ValueOf<EncompassingConfig>; // *Answer will probably require me to change this?

export const getRespectiveConfig = (
    nodes: Node[] | undefined,
): RespectiveConfig | undefined => {
    return determineAndReturnRespectiveConfigType(nodes); // Assume this returns type - AlphaConfig or BetaConfig
};
```

How `Modal` below receives the prop `currentlyEditingConfig`:

```js
interface Props {
    currentlyEditingConfig: BetaConfig | undefined;
}
```

Here is how it is used & where the issue lies. `currentlyEditingConfig` is a prop expecting to receive `BetaConfig` which is technically one of the possible types in `RespectiveConfig`, I then receive an error that says "Property 'id' is missing in type 'AlphaConfig' but required in type 'BetaConfig'.":

```js
<Modal
    currentlyEditingConfig={state.nodes ? getRespectiveConfig(state.nodes) : undefined}
/>
```

I assume where I have marked `*` in the first code block is where the issue would lie, I have tried to use variations of `Pick<K, T>` but unable to figure it out.

Relevant threads:

- [Turn typescript interface property types into union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128348/turn-typescript-interface-property-types-into-union)
- [How to pass optional parameters while enforcing one to be passed in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74848185/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-while-enforcing-one-to-be-passed-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempted solution (a hack I assume) - When calling Modal with the `currentlyEditingConfig` prop, I had to do this:

```js
<Modal
    currentlyEditingConfig={
        state.nodes 
          ? (getRespectiveConfig(state.nodes) as BetaConfig) 
          : undefined
    }
/>
```

Any proper solution greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not correct solution as long as `getRespectiveConfig` could return `AlphaConfig` which is not expected by `currentlyEditingConfig` property. You are just forcing TypeScript to make think, this will be `BetaConfig`, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks Vladislav Kibenko, I made an edit to my "solution" after your comment.

Comment: So the thing is `getRespectiveConfig` was meant to be generic for extracting various configs depending on the context. So I think if there were a proper way to fix this, it would be within the type declaration? - Where `RespectiveConfig` was declared

Comment: In my mind, you should create separate function extracting `BetaConfig` (`getBetaConfig`, for example) which will reuse `getRespectiveConfig` and check if it is really `BetaConfig`. For example, via checking if `id` property exists in received `RespectiveConfig`.